# I'm encountering an H14 'No web processes running' error with my Heroku app despite successful build and deploy

Tags: procfile, heroku-api

I am having an issue with my Heroku application. When I try to run it, I receive an error message 'No web processes running' (H14 error). The application was initially blank, then I tried to build and deploy it, which was successful. However, I still cannot access the app and keep getting the H14 error. Can you help me understand and resolve this issue?
The Procfile contains the following line: "web: gunicorn app:app."

have an HTML file called index.html that is powered by Flask, and it takes its programming from a Python file called app.py. The index.html file is located inside a folder named "templates," and the app.py file is in the project's root directory. Additionally, there are also files named .env, Procfile, and requirements.txt in the root directory of the project.

I have attempted several troubleshooting steps, including verifying the contents of my Procfile, confirming that gunicorn is listed in my requirements.txt file, and ensuring that my app is correctly defined in the specified Python file. However, I am still encountering the issue.